# How does each_slice work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, ienumerable, irb

Can some one explain how this enumerable works with example?
Data structure wise.
What is `p` in the loop?

`(1..10).each_slice(3) {|a| p a}`

```
             [1, 2, 3]
             [4, 5, 6]
             [7, 8, 9]
             [10]
```

Comment: To start with, `p` is just the name of a Ruby method that is built in, which is roughly equivalent to `puts object.inspect`.

Comment: The method is [Kernel#p](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p).  The Kernel module also provides the methods `puts`, `print`, `putc`, `printf`, etc.  As @Linuxios (why do I always want to put a 'u' before the 's'?) said, there is also [Object#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks for the links. I stopped trying to type SO usernames a long time ago...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable#each_slice(n)` when called with a block (`{ ... }`) takes chunks of `n` elements of the series and passes them to the block as arrays.

The block is an anonymous function with `| a |` being the argument list. So, `a` becomes the chunk on each invocation.

`p` is a built-in function which outputs a presentation of its argument (`a`) to `stdout`.

All in all, you are seeing the chunks/slices of three elements (plus the incomplete last one) being printed.

Obviously you've found the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) already.